# How to use if statment with a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list of two items. I would like to set a condition using the `if` statement. The condition needs to contain the `all` statement as well.

In other words,

Suppose I have the following list:

```
library(VineCopula)
x <- BiCop(0,0)
y <- BiCop(0,0)
z <- list(x, y)
```

I would like to have a condition that said that if all the `z[[i]]$tau` less or greater than a specific value, then `z` must be set to zero.

Here is my code (kindly note that my list can have any length. That is, the length is not fixed. Here, I fixed the length to two elements only, but my real data needs to be more than 2.):

```
     for (i in seq_len(m)){
  if (all( 0 <= z[[i]]$tau =< 0.15))
    z <- 0
}
```

How to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the `list` element, wrap with `all` on the logical condition to return a single `TRUE/FALSE`, use that in `if`, loop over the 'z' and assign the `tau` elements to 0

```
tau1 <- sapply(z, "[[", "tau") 
i1 <- all(tau1 >= 0 & tau1 <= 0.15)
if(i1) {
   z <- lapply(z, function(x) {x$tau <- 0; x})
}
```

---

The syntax `0 <= z[[i]]$tau =< 0.15` seems to mathematical which is not a correct `R` syntax as we need to have two expressions joined with `&`.  Also, as we are doing the check on `all` the `list` elements, we may need to do this in two `for` loop (if `for` loop is used) - first one to check if `all` meets the condition and second to do the assignment (in case the first returned TRUE) i.e.

```
i1 <- TRUE
# // first loop
for(i in seq_along(z)) {
     i1 <- i1 & z[[i]]$tau >= 0 & z[[i]]$tau <= 0.15
}
# // second loop
if(i1) {
   for(i in seq_along(z)) {
        z[[i]]$tau <- 0
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate it.  Yes, I am using `for` loop.

Comment: @Maryam thanks. I updated with `for` loop